# Accessing xrange internal structure

Tags: python, ctypes, cpython, xrange

I'm trying to use ctypes to extract data from internal python structures.  Namely, I'm trying to read the 4 fields in an xrange:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    long    start;
    long    step;
    long    len;
} rangeobject;
```

Is there any standard way of getting at such fields within python itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access data you need without `ctypes`:

```
>>> obj = xrange(1,11,2)
>>> obj.__reduce__()[1]
(1, 11, 2)
>>> len(obj)
5
```

Note, that `__reduce__()` method is exactly for serialization. Read [this chapter in documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-extension-types) for more information.

**Update**: But sure you can access internal data with `ctypes` too:

```
from ctypes import *

PyObject_HEAD = [
    ('ob_refcnt', c_size_t),
    ('ob_type', c_void_p),
]

class XRangeType(Structure):
    _fields_ = PyObject_HEAD + [
        ('start', c_long),
        ('step', c_long),
        ('len', c_long),
    ]

range_obj = xrange(1, 11, 2)

c_range_obj = cast(c_void_p(id(range_obj)), POINTER(XRangeType)).contents
print c_range_obj.start, c_range_obj.step, c_range_obj.len
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in the question that I need to be compatible with Python 2.5.  Serialization was only added in python 2.6.

Comment: Worked perfectly; thanks so much. (And now it is clear how to do this for general types)

Answer (score 0):

The ctypes module isn't meant for accessing Python internals.  ctypes lets you deal with C libraries in C terms, but coding in Python.

You probably want a C extension, which in many ways is the opposite of ctypes.  With a C extension, you deal with Python code in Python terms, but code in C.

UPDATED: Since you want pure Python, why do you need to access the internals of a built-in xrange object? xrange is very simple: create your own in Python, and do what you want with it.

Comment: In the ideal world, I would use one.

However, what I am distributing must be written in pure python; I cannot have the users to compile python extensions.

Comment: I'm implementing a library (open-source part of PiCloud(.com) ) which needs to serialize such objects in python 2.5.  
Note: I can always do a str(xrange_object) and then parse, but besides being very kludgey won't work for other C objects I'm trying to get at.